# Batch script to move file from scource to destination folder for files older than 30 day

Tags: windows, batch-file

i want to create the batch script which could copy the 30 days older files from one folder to another. And also deletes the 30 days old files from the source folder after copying to the destination folder

```
forfiles /p "c:\sourceFolder" /S /D -30  /C "cmd /c robocopy "C:\DestinationFolder"  "C:\sourceFolder" /mir @file : date>=30 days=nul"
```

Nothing has happened, not even error message is displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
robocopy sourceFolder targetFolder * /s /mov /minage:30 /l
```

If the list is correct, remove the /l (only list) from the command to do the move

Answer (score 0):

This robocopy only moves a few files and deleted my rar packages? not working at all as I would like to. I just want it to work as user3302083 wants. Just move folder that is 2 days old no other changes. Now I tried and it moved just a few files and deleted.

Comment: Sameera, I got a solution . might be this will help you .     ::- forfiles /p "C:\SeleniumIDE" /s /d -30 /c "cmd /c del @file : date >= 30 days >NUL" 


forfiles /p "Z:\TopPages" /S /D -30  /c "cmd /c robocopy "Z:\TopPages" "C:\SeleniumIDE" * /s /mov /minage:30